# Doesn't modifying original Map invalidate its submap or submap's iterator?

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I have original map (say, TreeMap). Then I get a subMap (in two ways - using SortedMap.subMap and NavigableMap.subMap) - now I have orig map and submap references.

Is there a problem if:

1. I modify (also structurally) orig map - any problem with submap?
   Like with subList?
2. If I got an iterator *from orig map or from submap* and then modified
   *either orig map or submap* (I get ConcurrentModificationException in **either** case, like in values(), getKeySet(), getEntrySet() collection views?)
3. I modify submap (shall be no problem for orig map - it shall change, right? That is the purpose of subMap - to work with orig map thrugh submap as a view).

Concerning Question 1: Oracle clarifies it only about [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)):

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined **if
>   the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way
>   other than via the returned list.** (Structural modifications are those
>   that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a
>   fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

Concerning iterator: Oracle is not clear about both subMap(...) methods: *Is both subMap(...) methods of TreeMap fall into "collection view methods" group right below?*

[TreeMap:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections
>   returned by all of this class's **"collection view methods"** are
>   fail-fast: *if the map is structurally modified at any time after the
>   iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own
>   remove method, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException*.

[Map:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

> The Map interface provides **three collection views**, which allow a map's
>   contents to be viewed as a set of keys, collection of values, or set
>   of key-value mappings.